# Call two function in one onchange = not working

Tags: function, onchange

I have been searching how to put more than one function in onchange and I found how something like this for example: `onchange = "function1(); function2();"`.
**My problem here is I have followed what does the example like, but only function1 is working, function2 is not working.** If I make it otherwise to `onchange = "function2(); function1();"`, only function2 is working, function1 is not working, the same.

Any ideas guys?
Thanks.

The functions, I used Ajax:

```
function1(test)
{
    var kode = test.value;
    if (!kode) return;
    xmlhttp.open('get', '../template/get_name-opr.php?kode='+kode, true);
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if ((xmlhttp.readyState == 4) && (xmlhttp.status == 200))
        {
            //alert(kode);
             document.getElementById("code").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
        return false;
    }
    xmlhttp.send(null);
}

function2(test)
{
    var kode = test.value;
    if (!kode) return;
    xmlhttp**1**.open('get', '../template/get_name2-opr.php?kode='+kode, true);
    xmlhttp**1**.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if ((xmlhttp**1**.readyState == 4) && (xmlhttp**1**.status == 200))
        {
            //alert(kode);
             document.getElementById("code2").innerHTML = xmlhttp**1**.responseText;
        }
        return false;
    }
    xmlhttp**1**.send(null);
}
```

To solve my problem, I created two xmlhttp different. (xmlhttp and xmlhttp1).

Comment: Did you see any JavaScript errors on any of the function ?

Comment: @ShashankKadne Hummm.. I don't know if it calls error, I see in the firebug and it says (the results of the function) for function1 "http://localhost/template/get_name-opr.php?kode=f Aborted (with red all fonts, means no response, doesn't have result),
function2 "http://localhost/template/get_name-opr.php?kode=f" (this is the one get response, does have result). That's it!
I'm confused (=,=)"a.

Comment: See if there is any error in error console(Tools>Error Console)

Comment: There is not any error, just got two results that I have mentioned above in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go through the link I gave, it seems to be problem with the way you are managing the `xmlhttprequest` objects, manage their instances properly, in your case because you are using the same `xmlhttprequest` for two simultaneous AJAX requests, only one of them is getting served. Either wait for one of them to get served or create two instances of the `xmlhttprequest`.

The statement `xmlhttp.readystate = function() {...}` obviously replaces the `readystate` property of that `xmlhttprequest` object, so on your second function, that is being replaced( because you are using the `xmlhttprequest` for both of them ). This is why you are seeing the funny behaviour.

Comment: It works, Mr Navneeth. I created two xmlhttp(xmlhttp and xmlhttp1) to put it on each function. That's how it works.
Thankyou Mr. Navneeth.

Answer (score 1):

Call function2() at the end of function1().

```
onchange = "function1()"

function1(){
...
function1 body;
...
function2()
}
```

Comment: Can you please post your functions, i tried a simple alert() example with two functions and it works.

Comment: @Boris The functions, I used Ajax. Look at my post.

Comment: Try to debug your functions, i believe there is a problem with one of your functions.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the two function calls in one and call that function!

```
function myFirstFunction() {
   //body
}

function mySecondFunction() {
   //body
}

//Call this guy.
function myWrappedFunction() {
   myFirstFunction();
   mySecondFunction();
}
```

Comment: I don't know what's happening in your browser, it should work the way you mentioned. Try this way, still if it doesn't... you know what I mean.

Comment: I have followed your codes, nothing happens ~(T___T)~ both functions are not working *wondering*

Comment: try putting an alert as the first line of each function definition, that will assure, that the functions are indeed being called. Now you should look for some funny behaviour in your server.

Comment: also try putting an `alert(xmlhttp.readyState)` in the function definition for the `onreadystatechange` callback and review the status codes.

Comment: are you creating a new xmlhttprequest for each of your requests?

Comment: try following this thread too : http://www.ozzu.com/website-design-forum/multiple-ajax-calls-the-same-time-t67591.html

Comment: Thankyou Mr Navneeth for you response. I did put alert at the first line of each function, you know what it's so funny really really funny, it worked like a charm BUT if I remove the alert of each function it came back like before, only one worked. What should I do?